# Slow WUA (Windows Update API)

Tags: windows, winapi, powershell, updates, windows-update

I'm working on a PowerShell script to do some Windows Update tasks. Most tasks center around getting a collection of Windows Updates that have not yet been applied, using the code snippet below. Once that collection is returned, I iterate through it and perform such tasks as hiding, downloading, or installing the updates.

I notice that this code can take anywhere from 6 to 115 sceconds to run. Typically the longer runs are after the machine has restarted or been idle for more than 15 minutes.

But if I open the Windows Update control panel item, it *instantly* knows how many updates are outstanding, and can give me a list (collection) of those outstanding updates. If I click WU's "check for updates" link, it will take >10 seconds to check again, and sometimes that check will yield different results than it "knew" instantly when I opened it.

So I assume that WUA maintains a cached collection of updates somewhere, probably updated automatically once daily. **My question: how can my code access that cache, rather than running the longer "check for updates" code shown below? Specifically, I am hoping to quickly obtain an [IUpdateCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386107(v=vs.85).aspx) to work with.**

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session            
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.Online = $false  #tested $true and $false; $true slightly slower
$Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'"
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria)           
$SearchResult.Updates
```

Note that all this is happening on a current, Windows2012R2 system.

Comment: Have you checked the WindowsUpdate.log to see what is happening? What does `$Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()` show before you run this?

Comment: ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF - nothing unusual in WindowsUpdate.log. I see the $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount() start and complete instantly (returning "46"); the $Searcher.Search($Criteria) take over six seconds to complete. No errors.

Comment: It's interesting, I know you can get the number from the registry but all that info isn't in there. Maybe its reading manifest files from the SoftwareDistribution folder?

Answer (score 3):

Look like the cache is a CAB file called wsusscn2.cab that is regularly downloaded from MSFT. There is a direct link to it in the msdn link I posted below. Perhaps write a script that downloads that once per day/week (maybe to a network share if this is going to be a widely deployed script), and then change your script to force it to always look at the CAB file instead of online. **Like this:**

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session       
$UServiceManager = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager
$UService =  $UServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", "c:\wsusscn2.cab") 
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.ServerSelection = 3  
$Searcher.ServiceID = $UService.ServiceID
$Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'"
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria)           
$SearchResult.Updates
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387290(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This seems unlikely. 1) A search of my computer finds no copies of wsusscan2.cab 2) In all the documentation I can find, it says this file must be downloaded before use. So, while it's one way to approach things, it seems not to be the cache that the system uses.

Comment: Additionally: using an Invoke-Webrequest, the (currently 103 MB) file download takes longer than my original method did!

Comment: usage of the `Wsusscn2.cab` offline cache is official and documented - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647642.aspx - mbsa fyi produces, ime, similar results to the powershell approach

Comment: Patrick: yes, it's documented. One can script doing it that way, and I have (https://gist.github.com/bklockwood/716d9f582dd78a9e6e9e) .. but this doesn't seem to be how the *OS itself* actually caches such data. Thanks for the input, though.